# Разбить сбалансированное бинарное дерево на пару сбалансированных деревьев

Tags: c++, c, дерево

По заданному сбалансированному бинарному дереву, элементами которого являются случайные целые числа, создать два новых сбалансированных бинарных дерева, в одном из которых разместить положительные значения вершин заданного дерева, а во втором – отрицательные. Предусмотреть вывод содержимого вершин построенных деревьев.

Пока вот такие функции для создания нашего рандомного первого сбалансированого дерева, дальше много чего пытался делать, но все без успеха. Правильный результат получался только если поочередно копировать значения с дерева в масив и потом уже с него формировать деревья. Но такое решение точно не пойдет. Буду рад помощи

```
struct Tree

    {       
             int data;
             struct Tree *left;     //Tree *left; 
             struct Tree *rigth;   //Tree *rigth; 
     };

struct Tree *tree_balance(int n)

    {
           struct Tree *q;
           int nl,nr;
           if (n==0) q=0;                                  //q=NULL;
           else {
                      nl=n/2; nr=n-nl-1;
                      q=malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));   //(C++) q=new Tree;
                      q->data=rand()%100 - 50;
                      q->left=tree_balance(nl);
                      q->rigth=tree_balance(nr);
                };
           return q;   
    }
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, заголовок в порядок. Опечатки, слишком длинный, всё что найдёте. А я вам помогу с решением задачи. Она забавная.

Comment: Исправил, не судите строго, русский не мой родной язык

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сбалансированное дерево легко построить если есть функция которая указывает куда вставлять новый элемент. Последний аргумент `path` разбивается на биты и в зависимости от бита выбирается поддерево: `0` - левое, `1` - правое:

```
node_t *insert_to_path(node_t *root, int value, int path) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        node->value = value;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        return node;
    }
    node_t **child = (path % 2 == 0) ? &root->left : &root->right;
    *child = insert_to_path(*child, value, path / 2);
    return root;
}
```

Эту функцию надо правильно применить. Структура `builder_t` хранит дерево и счётчик вставляемых элементов. Этот счётчик и служит значением `path`. Подумайте сами почему получается сбалансированное дерево:

```
typedef struct builder_t builder_t;
struct builder_t {
    int n;
    node_t *root;
};

void insert(builder_t *b, int value) {
    b->root = insert_to_path(b->root, value, b->n);
    ++b->n;
}
```

Например, сбалансированное случайное дерево:

```
node_t *balanced_random_tree(int n) {
    builder_t b = {0, NULL};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        insert(&b, rand() % 101 - 50);
    }
    return b.root;
}
```

Разбить дерево на "отрицательные" и "положительные" деревья можно так:

```
void split(const node_t *root, builder_t *negative, builder_t *positive) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    split(root->left, negative, positive);
    if (root->value < 0) {
        insert(negative, root->value);
    }
    if (root->value > 0) {
        insert(positive, root->value);
    }
    split(root->right, negative, positive);
}
```

Всё вместе:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_t node_t;
struct node_t {
    int value;
    node_t *left;
    node_t *right;
};

typedef struct builder_t builder_t;
struct builder_t {
    int n;
    node_t *root;
};

node_t *insert_to_path(node_t *root, int value, int path) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        node->value = value;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        return node;
    }
    node_t **child = (path % 2 == 0) ? &root->left : &root->right;
    *child = insert_to_path(*child, value, path / 2);
    return root;
}

void insert(builder_t *b, int value) {
    b->root = insert_to_path(b->root, value, b->n);
    ++b->n;
}

void print(const node_t *root, int level) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        print(root->left, level + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i) {
            printf("    ");
        }
        printf("%d\n", root->value);
        print(root->right, level + 1);
    }
}

node_t *balanced_random_tree(int n) {
    builder_t b = {0, NULL};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        insert(&b, rand() % 101 - 50);
    }
    return b.root;
}

void split(const node_t *root, builder_t *negative, builder_t *positive) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    split(root->left, negative, positive);
    if (root->value < 0) {
        insert(negative, root->value);
    }
    if (root->value > 0) {
        insert(positive, root->value);
    }
    split(root->right, negative, positive);
}

int main() {
    node_t *random_tree = balanced_random_tree(20);
    print(random_tree, 0);
    printf("--------\n");

    builder_t negative = {0, NULL};
    builder_t positive = {0, NULL};
    split(random_tree, &negative, &positive);
    
    print(negative.root, 0);
    printf("--------\n");
    print(positive.root, 0);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror balanced-tree.c 
>
> $ ./a.out 
>                 -49
>             -6
>         2
>             15
>     4
>                 39
>             -6
>         -42
>             1
> -18
>                 -45
>             44
>         6
>             -31
>     -18
>                 -16
>             -11
>         -38
>             -20
>                 41
> --------
>             -16
>         -18
>     -6
>             -38
>         -31
> -49
>             -11
>         -45
>     -6
>             -20
>         -42
>             -18
> --------
>         1
>     4
>         6
> 2
>         44
>     15
>         39
>             41
> ```

Comment: Идея использования порядкового номера для распределения хороша.

Answer (score 0):

У вас же дерево не является деревом поиска. Тогда проще.

Выполняете обход первого дерева. Встретили отрицательный элемент - кладёте в соответствующее новое дерево. А при вставке смОтрите - если левое поддерево больше, вставляете в правое, если равны - то в левое. Понадобится ввести в узле дополнительное поле - например, размер поддерева.

Comment: Спасибо за реакцию. В теории звучит круто, но с реализацией вообще нет вариантов ( как например потом из функции вернуть эти 2 новых дерева)

Comment: Например  - параметры функции  - три указателя - корень старого дерева, и два корня новых деревьев

Comment: пробовал сначала пройти дерево узнать сколько всего там + и - элементов, и потом уже с этими данными формировать новое дерево, но вся трудность в том что когда из одного дерева копируешь в другое, то получаеться каша, как только находит не положительный элемент